# Reusing a custom "getter" in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I make something like this...more compact?

```
def token 
  if authorized?
    return t.token
  else
    raise Error('unauthorized!')
  end
end

def secret
  if authorized?
    return t.secret
  else
    raise Error('unauthorized!')
  end
end
```

Feels like way too much re-use at the moment.

Comment: On line 3 you return `token`, but in this scope "token" doesn't exist except as the method itself, which would cause infinite recursion in this case. The same for `secret` on line 9. Did you omit some code? Having the whole code will help us provide the best answer.

Comment: @Jordan: Considering the lack of `end` in the original meant the snippet wouldn't compile, I think he did.

Answer (score 4):

Add a filter that will run before the token or secret methods are called.

```
before_filter :check_authorization, :only => [ :token, :secret ]
```

Then add a method that will check if user is authorized,

```
def check_authorization
    if !authorized?
        raise DropboxError('User is not authorized')
    end
end

def token
    @token
end

def secret
    @secret
end
```

If token and secret are already properties of your model defined with `:attr_accessor` or something like that, you could eliminate the token and secret methods altogether as they are simple getters with no logic.